# SQL Server : Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I need to declare globally variable as counter

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0;
```

And then use a stored procedure, but it always tells me that `@counter` must be declared as scalar variable

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE proc_counter_type 
     @type NVARCHAR(15), 
     @dateFirst DATE,
     @dateSecond DATE
AS
    SELECT @counter = COUNT(title_id)
    FROM books
    WHERE type = @type AND (datum BETWEEN @dateFirst AND @dateSecond)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "globally variable" [sic].  SQL Server only understands local variables in the stored procedure.  You may need to pass the value in.

Comment: You can use temporary tables: local or global.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `@Counter` as an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE proc_counter_type @type nvarchar(15), @dateFirst date, @dateSecond date, @Counter int OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @counter = COUNT(title_id)
    FROM books
    WHERE type = @type
      AND (datum BETWEEN @dateFirst AND @dateSecond);
END;
```

Then you execute the SP as:

```
DECLARE @counter int;
--Other Params
EXEC proc_counter_type, @Type, @dateFirst, @dateSecond, @Counter OUTPUT;

PRINT @Counter;
```